# Separating blocks of data into multiple dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have a .txt file with the following format:

```
Test_Type: SOT
Test_Date: 10/18/2017
Test_Time: 07:39:27
Condition_Name: SOT
Condition_Number: 1
Trial_Number: 1
Sway_Gain: 1.0
Data_Rate(hz): 100
Accessory_Channels: 0
Test_Duration(sec): 20
Number_of_Data_Points: 2000

UNITS          (lb)           (lb)           (lb)           (lb)           (lb)           
DP             LF             RR             SH             LR             RF            
1              90.04          20.31          0.00           18.36          81.64          
2              90.04          20.31          0.00           18.75          81.64          
3              90.04          20.31          0.00           18.75          81.64   
...
2000           88.48          19.14          0.00           20.31
```

In the file, there are **several blocks of data, each preceded by the categorical header**. Some blocks are 2000 lines, others are 500 lines.

My goal is to divide the file into separate dataframes or .csv, one per block of data.

something like:

```
for line in lines:
    if line contains "Test_Type":
        create new .csv
```

I plan to recombine all the new files back into a single dataframe at the end, with the categorical data extracted.

Thank you!!

Each output dataframe would look something like this:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptvaw.png)

The final dataframe would look like this (with a column reconciling categorical data):

[final combined df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwtpz.png)

The overall problem I am trying to solve is how to extract categorical data for each block of data and representing it in a column in the df, that is accurate for each different block (i.e. test type, condition, and trial for each datapoint)

Comment: Can you give an example of what your output dataframe from that input will look like?

Comment: just added an image of sample output!